# I get "Error code: 1054. Unknown column 'persoon_id' in 'geboorte_informatie'"

Tags: mysql

I get "Error code: 1054. Unknown column 'persoon_id' in 'geboorte_informatie'"

This is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS geboorte_informatie;

CREATE TABLE `geboorte_informatie`(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
naam VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE INDEX naam_uk (naam));

insert into geboorte_informatie
values(9,'Suriname');

ALTER TABLE `adres_boek` . `geboorte_informatie`
ADD COLUMN `geboorte_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '45' AFTER `persoon_id`,
ADD INDEX `land_fk_idx` (`land_id`);
```

Comment: What's your question?- there is no column persoon_id in your published table. and there is no column land_id either?

Comment: you declared a column `persoon_id` and `land_id` that doesn't exist in the table